# How to calculate Hermite interpolation without slope in the end points (unknown derivatives)?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-calculus, hermite-polynomials

In class, the following exercise was proposed.

***Determine the natural cubic spline that passes through the points (0,1) (1, 0) (2, 0.5) (3, 1). Use the Hermite method***

I need to interpolate a function, but to get it I need the slopes at those same points (that's to be able to use the method of divided differences, which is the only method I know). The exercise did not provide us with such data, that's where my question appeared. How do I get the slopes at those points? Or is there some other (Hermite) method that allows me to interpolate the function I need?

Any clue that helps me solve the exercise shown above would be of great help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline You need to write a linear system of equation satisfied by the second derivatives at the nodes (which come from differentiability conditions at the nodes). Solve the system and use the Hermite representation to write the spline. For natural splines, the second derivatives at the interval bounds are zero, so you have only $2$ equations.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where do I get those conditions that you mention? here I do not apply the method of divided differences?

Comment: I forgot the most important: cubic splines are piecewise cubic functions. That is, on each interval it's a cubic polynomial. And additionally, together they form a $C^2$ function, so there are conditions on two consecutive polynomials $p_i$ (on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$) and $p_{i+1}$ (on $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$), i.e. $p_i(x_i)=p_{i+1}(x_i),p'_i(x_i)=p'_{i+1}(x_i),p''_i(x_i)=p''_{i+1}(x_i)$.

Comment: I found this, but don't explain where that equation comes from, I assume it's an integrated natural cubic spline, but is this some kind of trick? or is there any analysis behind?  
\begin{equation} \left\{\begin{matrix} M_1 = M_n = 0 \\ \frac{1}{6}(x_j - x_{j-1})M_{j-1} + \frac{1}{3}(x_{j+1}-x_{j-1})M_j + \frac{1}{6}(x_{j+1} -x_j)M_{j+1} = \frac{y_{j+1}-y_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j} - \frac{y_j - y_{j-1}}{x_j - x_{j-1}} \end{matrix}\right. \end{equation}
[I found this,but, Where does the equation come from?](http://comunidad.clavemat.org/blocks/simplebloque/preguntas.php?categoryid=7&bttpregunta=581831)